# Conversion of Flat Source File to XML in SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)

Tags: xml, text, ssis

I have looked everywhere. MSDN article, forums and Stack Exchange. But I can't find the solution to my problem. Hoping to get help here.

So I have a requirement to convert **Text Source File to XML** using SSIS Package. There is no proven way on the Interwebs. There are lots of ways to generate XML file if source is SQL Server database. But my requirement is to convert it directly from Source with no SQL involvement in the middle. The closest I have reached is the following code which I got from somewhere.

```
'Here is one way that i can suggest to everyone for converting 
' Flat File to XML using the Script Component "Destination"
' in the data flow task.
'Source: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic709064-148-1.aspx

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper

Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits UserComponent

Private targetFile As String
Private xmlWriter As IO.StreamWriter
Private rootElement As String = "Root"
Private rowElement As String = "Row"
Private columns As Integer()
Private Columnnames As String()

Public Overrides Sub AcquireConnections(ByVal Transaction As Object)
    targetFile = CType(Me.Connections.DesFile.AcquireConnection(Nothing), String)
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
    xmlWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(targetFile, False)
    xmlWriter.WriteLine(FormatElement(rootElement))
    Dim input As IDTSInput90 = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection(0)
    ReDim columns(input.InputColumnCollection.Count)
    columns = Me.GetColumnIndexes(input.ID)
    Dim column As IDTSInputColumn90
    ReDim Columnnames(input.InputColumnCollection.Count)
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0
    For Each column In Me.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection(0).InputColumnCollection
        Columnnames(counter) = column.Name
        counter = counter + 1
    Next
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
    xmlWriter.WriteLine(FormatElement(rootElement, True))
    xmlWriter.Close()
End Sub


'Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
'Dim column As IDTSInputColumn90
' Dim rowType As Type = Row.GetType()
'Dim columnValue As Reflection.PropertyInfo

'With xmlWriter
'.Write(FormatElement(rowElement))
' For Each column In Me.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection(0).InputColumnCollection
'columnValue = rowType.GetProperty(column.Name)
' Try
' .Write(FormatElement(column.Name) + columnValue.GetValue(Row, Nothing).ToString() + FormatElement(column.Name, True))
'Catch ex As Exception
' Write(CInt(FormatElement(column.Name) + "" + FormatElement(column.Name, True)))
'End Try
' Next
' .WriteLine(FormatElement(rowElement, True))
' End With
' End Sub

Public Overrides Sub ProcessInput(ByVal InputID As Integer, ByVal Buffer As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer)
    While Buffer.NextRow()
    'Dim values As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    xmlWriter.Write(FormatElement(rowElement))
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Counter = 0
    For Each Index As Integer In columns
        Dim Value As Object = Buffer(Index)
        xmlWriter.Write(FormatElement(Columnnames(Counter).ToString()) + Value.ToString() + FormatElement(Columnnames(Counter).ToString(), True))
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next
    xmlWriter.WriteLine(FormatElement(rowElement, True))
    End While
End Sub

Private Function FormatElement(ByVal elementName As String) As String
    Return FormatElement(elementName, False)
End Function

Private Function FormatElement(ByVal elementName As String, ByVal closingTag As Boolean) As String
    Dim returnValue As String
    If closingTag Then
        returnValue = "</"
    Else
        returnValue = "<"
    End If
    returnValue += elementName + ">"

    Return returnValue
End Function

End Class
```

But I am getting error in the following line:
    targetFile = CType(Me.Connections.DesFile.AcquireConnection(Nothing), String)

I have tried to replace DesFile with my connection manager: conTargetXML.
The error I am getting is following:

> Error 2   'conTargetXML' is not a member of 'SC_f8187669a2e147ab9d856ec04791a173.vbproj.Connections'

So I have following questions:

1. Can I make the above code work?

   Is there any other preferred way to convert Text source file to XML using any extension/add-on, since SSIS provides no native way as Target XML component.

Please help.

Comment: Instead of AcquireConnections, you could consider passing the target filename as a variable.

Comment: Is that error indicating a mismatch between the connection that exists in your project and what you *think* the name is?  Maybe posting more of the .dtsx could help.

Comment: Does the screenshot helps? The name of connection is provided here: http://i.imgur.com/VYwEOEE.jpg